# How do I customize themes in monaco editor

Tags: typescript, next.js, customization, monaco-editor

I am currently making a code editor with Monaco. Javascript and typescript syntax highlighting in Monaco only highlights keywords like dark blue, string as brown, and number as light greenish yellow.

I want to customize the vs-dark theme such that variables are marked with light blue, types are dark green, and functions with yellow.
Will this work :

```
monaco.editor.defineTheme('default', {
    base: 'vs-dark',
    inherit: true,
    rules: [
      {
        token: "identifier",
        foreground: "#9CDCFE"
      },
      {
        token: "identifier.function",
        foreground: "#DCDCAA"
      },
      {
        token: "type",
        foreground: "#1AAFB0"
      },
    ],
    colors: {}
    });
monaco.editor.setTheme('default')
```

If possible, please give me a list of all such tokens to help me customize even more.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is partially possible. Unfortunately, I don't think you can highlight function names separately from variables (I didn't find it). But you can create your custom tokenizer for JS (which I think is an overkill) to support different color for function names.

Here is a [monaco-editor playground link](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html?source=v0.38.0#XQAAAAIpAwAAAAAAAABBqQkHQ5NjdMjwa-jY7SIQ9S7DNlzs5W-mwj0fe1ZCDRFc9ws9XQE0SJE1jc2VKxhaLFIw9vEWSxW3yscw2_RKcnmJTiNUtu5Yj0D6Gs0MBQaKsfYDizyTgFcvIJCLb0TgTVKA3hWkzTeGC6sY4F9ZD38Vf-oD9Kou5bpzeFP16YxpwZPLMuFYTXrbUCCDqM8vhwKReXz1lgKwc3q7GyrzWbipcH7ev-G4EsQeV_Y_xizVKUfIIX5g68TOTz8ezFZnueqPUHsZq547M1to1lv9pc4NjSmqce7EJ2RclkpncGLjuo1cDSWSF9O6Mra9QNisp2au67S0Bj7eUMBetWmJK4kAUDIem2y-PAOv4s_LlgXn3Ofu4nt_4m3zLVR5MUyKUeCF7_lBUJ-D5YA5DOrY1A_qTJoErP0hT4wChq31sbHEmKhYSUJ0qtOTImN_jnQepfq0udxME35IBfLXUoSvDnYP831b_LbMokoXHoymv3NUJ7vaHNHPBvRKF6pE48vG0Rp8GW0LKeTKWYM_EsIwYEqtHZf_i1YKgNOp4EGpEP4x0wqvlIhe26qngYYfQXPfHkkegOMHRRxsLX6-AGNzdn9BIyfaIESh-60kCIU6S-FJT4ecqF__Kj_wAA) with your theme.

Also, there is a [repository](https://github.com/brijeshb42/monaco-themes/) with different monaco-editor themes to try, you can look for other customizable tokens there.